# Django url pattern doesn't match

Tags: regex, django, python-2.7

I am using new Django 1.8 app to learn Django.

I am stumped as to how to get this my simple url to be resolved by urls.py

I create the url in another view as:

```
<a href="/photoview/{{photo.id}}/"}>
```

I can successfully pass this url to the browser as:

http://localhost:8000/photoview/300/

I am expecting that this url can be matched by the  urls.py expression:

```
url('r^photoview/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.photoview),
```

But this is not working.  I have tried variations of this but none have worked so far, such as:

```
url('r^photoview/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.photoview),
```

I get this message in browser when it fails to match

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/photoview/300/

Using the URLconf defined in asset.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^$ [name='index']
^time/$
^about/$
^accounts/$
^photos/$
^tags/$
^users/$
r^photoview/(?P<id>\d+)/$
^static\/photos\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, photoview/300/, didn't match any of these.
```

Appreciate any help getting this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have `url('r^photoview/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.photoview),`
you want `url(r'^photoview/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.photoview),`

(Note the r is in front of the string, not the first character)

As noted in [docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls),

> The 'r' in front of each regular expression string is optional but
>   recommended. It tells Python that a string is “raw” – that nothing in
>   the string should be escaped

Also note that you should use a friendly name in your url definition (e.g. photoview) and then use {% url 'photoview' photo.id %} in your template instead of hardcoding the URL pattern.

Comment: Aah, totally missed that. Thanks.

Comment: `{% url 'photoview' photo.id %}` - don't forget the quotes around the name.